# Octopress: how to mark up pseudocode?

Tags: markdown, pseudocode, octopress

I'd like to include some pseudocode on my Octopress-powered blog. However, I'm not sure what to do here - code markup isn't really what I need, because I'm not really writing *code*, or at least any code I can find in the list of those available to Github-flavoured markdown. I have set up my Octopress for LaTeX support (using [this example](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/03/10/writing-math-equations-on-octopress/)), but I'm not sure if it'll let me use `algorithmics`, which is my package of choice for pseudocode.

Any and all suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible with markdown. You could use a pseudocode editor or write your own syntax configuration